# How can i validate the name input with allow numbers

Tags: reactjs, antd

Why the rules are not working? i am using antd inputs, now i want to validate the fields,  what thing i need to do to use the rules for the inputs?

```
<Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish}  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        autoComplete="off">
        <Form.Item className="form-item" label={'name'} rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your name!',
          },
        ]}>
          <Input name='name'  />

        </Form.Item>
       

        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
```

i want to validate if 'name' just have letters not numbers, how can i do that?

Comment: you can check value of input by using regex /[^0-9]+/.test(name) returns true if there no any number into string

Comment: have you tried   ```<Input name='name'  htmlType='text'/>```

Comment: i want to use rules to apply regex rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your name!',
          },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish} onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        autoComplete="off">
        <Form.Item className="form-item" label={'name'}
            rules={[
                {
                    pattern: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/),
                    message: 'No Numbers Allowed'
                },
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your name!',
                }
            ]}>
            <Input name='name' />
    
        </Form.Item>
    
    
        <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                submit
            </Button>
        </Form.Item>
    </Form>;
```

Comment: Will not accept all latin chars such as "á", "é", "ô" etc